# Read with boost::program_options and push_back onto std::vector?

Tags: c++, boost, boost-program-options

I have a configuration file which contains a list of endpoint entries.  Each entry is labeled with a heading of [endpt/n] (for the nth endpoint), and consists of a MAC and IP address.  I'd like to use boost::program_options to read the addresses as strings, and push_back the results onto two vectors.  I've looked through the program_options documentation, but I haven't been able to find what I'm looking for...  Here's an example of an endpoint entry:

```
[endpt/2]
mac=ff-22-b6-33-91-3E
ip=133.22.32.222
```

Here's the code I'm currently using to add each endpoint's MAC and IP options to the boost::options_description:

```
std::vector<std::string> mac(NUM_ENDPTS);
std::vector<std::string>  ip(NUM_ENDPTS);

for(int e = 0; e < NUM_ENDPTS; e++)
{
    //convert endpoint 'e' to a string representing endpoint heading
    std::stringstream tmp;   tmp.clear();   tmp.str("");   tmp << e;
    std::string strEndpt = tmp.str();
    std::string heading = "endpt/"+strEndpt;

    cfig_file_options.add_options()
        ((heading+".mac").c_str(), po::value<std::string>(&mac[e]), ("ENDPT MAC")
        ((heading+".ip").c_str(),  po::value<std::string>( &ip[e]), ("ENDPT IP")
    ;
}

po::variables_map vm;
po::store(po::parse_config_file(config_stream, cfig_file_options), vm);
po::notify(vm);
```

This code works fine, but for a few reasons, I'd like to declare empty vectors for the MAC and IP addresses, and push_back the options onto them as boost reads them.  I'm new to Boost, so any suggestions on better ways to read a list, or any other help would be greatly appreciated.  Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is straightforward to do exactly as you want.  First, use `po::value< vector< std::string > >` instead of `po::value< std::string >` as program-options provides special support of vectors.  Then, reference your two vectors directly as

```
typedef std::vector< std::string > vec_string;

cfig_file_options.add_options()
  ((heading+".mac").c_str(), po::value< vec_string >(&mac), "ENDPT MAC")
  ((heading+".ip").c_str(),  po::value< vec_string >( &ip), "ENDPT IP")
;
```

The key here is that all mac and ip addresses use common vectors for storage.  I should point out that this won't necessarily associate the endpt number in the ini file with the correct index in the vector, unless a strict order is maintained in the file.

Comment: Thanks for the response!  I'm still having issues though... when I replace `po::value` with `po::vector`, I get errors saying `error: 'vector' is not a member of 'po'`.  (I didn't include it in the OP, but I'm using `namespace po = boost::program_options;`)  Could this be a version problem?  I'm using Boost 1.40...

Comment: No, it was not a version problem; my code was broken. I've corrected it. Also, I find it interesting that `options_description` does not take a `std::string` for the first parameter even in v. 1.41.1.

Comment: The code compiles now, but I'm still having some issues.  Using your `typedef std::vector< std::string > vec_string;`, when I declare empty vectors (`vec_string mac;`) the code seg-faults.  If I allocate space for the expected number of endpoints (`vec_string mac(NUM_ENDPTS);`) only the first string in the vector gets written to, and it gets overwritten with each subsequent configuration file entry.  Is there something else I need to add to my `po::store(po::parse_config_file(...))` command?

Comment: @tpm, you can try setting `multitoken()` on each of them. But, I have no idea if it will work, and I can't tell from reading the code.

Comment: Still no dice...  I'll keep poking at it, thanks again for all the help!